# Run pmd on a set of files in gradle

Tags: git, gradle, pmd

I work with a legacy product that is a number of years old.
We moved over from ant to gradle a few years ago. Now I want to add pmd checks on all my files. 
When I ran the check on the 3500 files in the product. The problem is when you run this kind of analyze on old files it tend to result in a lot of violations. In this case around 10000, which is too many to start working on.

My idea is to start check all java files with pmd starting from now (that is from a specific commit/tag in git)
Is it possible to specify the set of files that pmd evaluates from a git expression like:

def targetFiles = "git diff --name-only 85d1633..HEAD".execute()"

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe it is possible to specify a list of files via Gradle's PMD plugin.

You could Google "pmd make rule set" to see the PMD documentation on creating a custom ruleset (for PMD 5.1.x -- http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.1.1/howtomakearuleset.html). You could probably cobble together a ruleset with just the `<include-pattern>` elements you dynamically create.

I'd suggest an alternative approach though. Instead of turning on all the PMD checks immediately, just pick one, turn it on, and fix those violations. This should be a more manageable number of violations. Repeat this process, one rule at a time, until you have all the rules you care about turned on.